# Toggle Scroll DIV content on hover and out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wanted to make a div, and on hover on that div the contnet in the div must be scrolled to bottom, i have done the following code but its not working as desired, at the first hover it directly goes to bottom of the div height and on second hover the trasition works properly

```
.komal {
      overflow: hidden;
      height: 212px;
      position: relative;
  }
  .imgpos {
      position: absolute;
      transition: all 1s ease-out 0s;
  }

<div class="col-12 col-lg-4" id="outgov" style="height: auto;">
  <div class="card card-shadowed card-hover-shadow komal dhiraj">
    <div class="card-block text-center imgpos">
      <img src="assets/home_solutions/outsourcing-governance.png" width="30%" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
      <h2 class="card-title text-center">Outsourcing Governance</h2>
      <hr class="hr">
      <div class="row" id="outgov_hidden" style="background-color: white; z-index: 9; margin-left:-20px; padding-bottom: 20px;">
        <div class="text-center"><br>
          <h4 class="modal-title" style="color: #000">Outsourcing Governance Practice Made Easy</h4>
          <a style="margin-bottom:5px;" class="btn btn-info" href="#">Learn More</a>
          <br><br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
      var xH
      $('.dhiraj').hover(
      function () {
          xH = $(this).children(".imgpos").css("height");
          xH = parseInt(xH);
          xH = xH - 280;
          xH = "-" + xH + "px";
          $(this).children(".imgpos").css("top", xH);
      }, function () {
          $(this).children(".imgpos").css("top", "0px");
      });
  });
```

I want it to be working properly so please help that what can be done to make it work properly and look good
You can check the live demo on following link: http://sequentia.xyz/demo/demo
I want to make it (desired)like: http://domo.com (A solution for every role section on homepage of given desired link)

Please help me working it as desired like domo with my current color scheme

Comment: use slideDown() function of Jquery

Comment: @RaviPatil Can you please provide an example

Comment: @swap, you can try mouseover too , something like this - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/VQqbGW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to specify the `top` value. Otherwise, CSS Transition would not know from what value to transition.

In short, edit your code with this:

```
.imgpos {
      top: 0px;
      position: absolute;
      transition: all 1s ease-out 0s;
}
```

If more explanation required, please do mention.

Comment: Please, do accept it as the correct answer as well!